# application stcuk after executing getwritablddatabse in android

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

I am struggling with a weird problem. I have written a code to create database, create table and to insert one row and retrive tha row using cursor.

My problem here is when I run for first time database got create and table also got created but row was not inserted. so I tried to debug the application when I started debug control processed **getWritabledatabase** and it doesn't move to Oncreate. Below is my code.

Main activity:

```
package com.example.testdb;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Database d=new Database(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

databse class

```
package com.example.testdb;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    String Tablename = "Table1";
    private String Column1 = "RegionID";
    private String Column2 = "RegionName";
    private String Column3 = "Currency";
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, "Test", null, 2);
        this.getWritableDatabase();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
        final String r_Table = "CREATE TABLE " + Tablename + " (" + Column1+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " + Column2 + " TEXT, " + Column3 + " Text) ";
        db.execSQL(r_Table);
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(Column1, 1);
        cv.put(Column2, "US");
        cv.put(Column3, "Dollar");
        db.insert(r_Table, null, cv);
        }
        catch(Exception e){

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("Select * from Table1", null);

        if (c != null ) {
            if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                //Toast.makeText(new MainActivity().getApplicationContext(), c.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("Rows are:"+c.getCount());

        }


    }
        c.close();


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this as I am struck with this for the last one week.

Thanks in advance
Siva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few changes to your code and tested the same on my device. The below works. I guess you were getting NullPointerException. Next time it would be better to include your logcat trace. You can use the below for reference.

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
String Tablename = "Table1";
private String Column1 = "RegionID";
private String Column2 = "RegionName";
private String Column3 = "Currency";


public Database(Context context) {
    super(context, "Test", null, 2);
    this.getWritableDatabase();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public void addValues()
{    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
   ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
   cv.put(Column2, "US");
   cv.put(Column3, "Dollar");
   db.insert(Tablename,null , cv);
}
public void getValues()
{
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); 
   Cursor c=db.rawQuery("Select * from Table1", null);

   if (c != null ) {
       if  (c.moveToFirst()) {

           System.out.println("Rows are:"+c.getCount());
   }


 }
   c.close();
 }
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Tablename + "("
                + Column1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + Column2 + " TEXT,"
                + Column3 + " TEXT" + ")";  
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE );



}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

In the MainActiivty, i had two buttons one to add values, one to get values

On Button add click

```
    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting .."); 
    Database db= new Database(MainActivity.this);
    db.addValues();
```

On Button get click

```
     Database db= new Database(MainActivity.this);
     db.getValues();
```

After clicking get button , the logact details

```
     05-20 12:54:23.625: I/System.out(29225): Rows are:1 //row count
```

Comment: Thanks Raghunandan... Explanation was very clear. But the reason I am using the insertion and retrive in oncreate is I need some tables to be loaded and spinner and text field to be loaded when application launches. Is there any wayout for this.

Comment: you can call getvalue function after inserting values and then load the values to spinner or textfield. It is easier for debugging also

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. If possible can you provide me a link or post code snippet for the **getvalue** function.

Comment: @siva check the above code. It has getValues() defined in Database. try the above

Comment: Ohh soory..I didn't notice it. insetead of writing the code in Oncrated, I can call the getvalue() function in Oncreate. right.. Thanks...I am marking the answer as solved

Comment: Don't call getvalue() from onCreate() call it from your activity class. After calling addValues() you can call getValues() in your activity class Database db= new Database(MainActivity.this);
        db.addValues();
        db.getValues()

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not do any Database operations in the database helper class. Second you need to call

```
helperClass.getWritableDatabase()
//i.e.
Database.getWritableDatabase() //in your case
```

to get a writable instance of the database. Calling insert in onCreate() of Helper class is just weird. getWritableDatabse() returns an instance SQLiteDatabase. perform operations there. I have another suggestion create a parser class or adapter class for database and perform operations there.

There is a hardcoding issue as well. You see you have declared column1 as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY and you are inserting "1" everytime, please remove it.

Comment: Thanks KKD for your reply. Actually I need some operations to be done when application launches, like Creating tables, inserting some default data and retriving the data to display in spinner and text fileds. That is the reason I am declaring in Oncreate. In case of not using Oncreate how to perform these default operations and Adapter class you mean to use "database adapter"?. If yes can you please give me sample code for that.

Comment: @siva you can check the answer below. i made few minor changes to your code and it works.

Comment: One more question KKD, Does OS performance execution effects application execution. Currently I am using OS with 4GB ram and virtual box for emulator

Comment: @siva are you talking about android os or your system os?

Comment: @ Raghunandan Effect of System OS on android OS

Comment: @siva to some extent yes. Your emulator may load slowly in some systems and faster in others. But i have not seen too much of a difference.